# What term is used to denote the distance between two types in an inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: c#, inheritance, terminology, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

I have an extension method for calculating the distance between a base type and a derived type, such that the same type would have return a value of 0 and a direct subtype would return a value of 1.  What is the most concise and commonly used term to describe this scalar quantity?

To be more specific, what could I name the following method that would make sense and effectively communicate the intention?

```
    public static int? CalculateHowDeeplyDerivedTheDescendantTypeIsFromTheBaseType(this Type baseType, Type descendantType)
    {
        baseType = baseType ?? typeof(System.Object);
        descendantType = descendantType ?? typeof(System.Object);
        if (!baseType.IsAssignableFrom(descendantType))
            return descendantType.IsAssignableFrom(baseType)
                       ? -1*CalculateHowDeeplyDerivedTheDescendantTypeIsFromTheBaseType(descendantType, baseType)
                       : null;
        if (baseType == descendantType)
            return 0;
        return CalculateHowDeeplyDerivedTheDescendantTypeIsFromTheBaseType(baseType, descendantType.BaseType) + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the term you're looking for is [Depth of Inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2011/05/19/code-metrics-depth-of-inheritance-dit.aspx).

> Depth of inheritance, also called depth of inheritance tree (DIT), is defined as “the maximum length from the node to the root of the tree”

Answer (score 3):

Bill the Lizard may be on to something. However, as a generalized option relating to [Graph Theory](http://people.hofstra.edu/geotrans/eng/methods/ch1m2en.html), you could refer to it as LengthOfPathToDerivedClass.

> Length of a Link, Connection or Path. Refers to the label associated with a link, a connection or a path. This label can be distance, the amount of traffic, the capacity or any attribute of that link. The length of a path is the number of links (or connections) in this path.